# Upgrading from Leopard to Mavericks

Tags: macos, upgrade, leopard

I have an iMac from 2008 that is currently running Leopard and I would like to upgrade to Mavericks. What ways are there to upgrade, while spending the least amount of money. Also, are there any special discounts that Apple offers to students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **purchase** Snow Leopard ($20 USD) and, then, upgrade to Mavericks at no cost, according to Apple's website: http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/

IDK if Apple has a discount program for students.

Comment: Yeah, **if and only if** you Mac is compatible with Mavericks. If it running Leopard, likely not. Check out this link to see. http://www.everymac.com/mac-answers/os-x-10.9-mavericks-faq/os-x-mavericks-compatible-macs-system-requirements.html

Comment: Yep, Steve, you're right! :)

Comment: A 2008 iMac *should* be compatible with Leopard (proof: this was posted from a mid-2007 iMac running Mavericks).

Comment: @SteveChambers I just finished upgrading. The computer can run Mavericks with absolutely no problem. :) It starts ever so slightly slower than it did with Leopard (one or two extra seconds) but it runs just as smoothly.

Comment: Very cool, glad to hear it!